# Can not assign to a struct member from map

Tags: dictionary, struct, go

Code:

```
type t_struct struct {
    player string
    id     int
}

func main() {
    dataA := make(map[string]t_struct)
    dataB := make(map[string]*t_struct)

    var playerA t_struct
    playerA.player = "tom"
    playerA.id = 1
    dataA["classA"] = playerA
    dataA["classA"].id = 2 // ERROR, why?

    playerB := new(t_struct)
    dataB["classB"] = playerB
    dataB["classB"].player = "rick"
    dataB["classB"].id = 3
}
```

And got error:

> cannot assign to dataA["classA"].id

I wonder why `dataA["classA"].id = 2` not worked but `dataB["classB"].id = 3` did? Is it the only way to save struct pointer into map if you want to modify member value of it?

Comment: This seems to be relevant: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3117

Comment: @Mikke so we just have a work around method to save struct pointer into map for now?

Comment: It seems so, since the issue's priority is set to "later". Hopefully, it will be addressed at some point. The work around mentioned in the issue comments with storing a temporary pointer, manipulating it, and then putting it back into the map seems to be the easiest solution for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `dataA["classA"]` if of type `t_struct`. That means that

```
dataA["classA"].id = 2
```

is equvalent to e.g.

```
t_struct{"some player", 42}.id = 2
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/JJ2vmKbeOD)

IOW, the struct value has no "home" and changing its field cannot be persisted. As the only possibility is a programmer's mistake, the compiler flags an error.

OTOH:

```
dataB["classB"]
```

has type `*t_struct`. Then

```
dataB["classB"].id = 3
```

is equivalent to

```
(*t_struct)(somePointer).id = 3
```

I.e., this *lvalue* has a "home". It's where the pointer points to. The change to the field will be "recorded" there and it is thus a valid Go operation (simple assignment to a struct field where the struct is referenced by a pointer).

Comment: In `C/C++` you can do something like `dataA[0].id = 2`, but in `go` `dataA["classA"].id = 2` is equivalent to `1 = 2` in `C/C++`, am I right?

Comment: @ReckHou: Considering e.g. `var dataA []t_struct`, `dataA[0].id = 2` is legal in Go as well. It's only map values which are not addressable.

Comment: @jnml: you should make it clear in your answer that the problem is only because indexing a map is not addressable. Otherwise it sounds like any expression of type `t_struct` cannot have its field altered.